# Fort Vaux "zombie" screams and sounds - Battlefield 1

Tags: battlefield-1

Does anyone already have a clue on what the weird sounds are in Fort Vaux in Battlefield 1? I heard it was an audiofile of an walrus or something.

I hope that any of you have some theory on this new easter egg in Battlefield 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-VXGjjyUbbw) that discusses these sounds and the possibilities behind it:

One theory is that the sounds are suppose to be reenacting insane soldiers. In World War I, some soldiers in the field demonstrated what was called [*Shell Shock*](https://miepvonsydow.wordpress.com/2013/12/28/shell-shock/), which is a type of reaction to being helpless during bombardments and war in general.  It is a form of PTSD (though PTSD wasn't a term yet at that time).  Some men illustrated mental breakdowns from this disorder and had to be hospitalized.  To relate this back to the question, the door that the sounds are heard as the world "Isolation" above it, which helps further back this claim.

Another theory as you've said is that it is zombies or it is a continuation of another Easter Egg in the game.  The Easter Egg in question is [the Marconi Easter Egg](http://bfee.co/wiki/marconi-easter-egg/), which appears to be a lengthy Easter Egg in Battlefield 1 that involves you going across all the multiplayer maps and listening to Morse code.  You unlock a dog tag for doing the Easter Egg, and after doing so, the telegraph stations will then be on a weird audio loop that some find rather creepy.  This could be a continuation or just a part of this Easter Egg.  It would make sense though to keep zombies in an "Isolation Room."

The last theory is (as you've also said), walrus noises.  The linked video above shows a comparison between the sounds from the door, and the same Walrus video that the noises are speculated to have been pulled from.  Admittedly, they do sound extremely similar.

Comment: Walrus survival mode in Bf1? I'd buy it.

Comment: yup haha. Thanx for reacting @Timmy Jim ill now go and try to find a vid with the "disturbing" noise over the telegraph stations.